# Compute Engine Managed VM takes too long to reboot

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-compute-engine

Friends. I have a Google App engine website that uses one module on Google Compute Engine. It uses the Python standard runtimes with the following configuration:

```
runtime: python27
threadsafe: true
vm: true

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1

Machine type: f1-micro (1 vCPU, 0.6 GB memory)

health_check:
  enable_health_check: True
  check_interval_sec: 5
  timeout_sec: 2
  unhealthy_threshold: 2
  healthy_threshold: 2
  restart_threshold: 4
```

The problem is that periodically this instance becomes "unhealthy" (it respondes with 503 http code) and stays like that for around 10 to 15 minutes. This happens even when there's no traffic/access to the app. Shouldn't this instance reboot after 4 failed health checks? Does it take 15 minutes to reboot?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how often do your health checks run

Comment: I set in the yaml file as following: "check_interval_sec: 5". I believe this means it runs every 5 seconds.